# WPF: Is there a free (open source) alternative to Telerik DataFilter?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik

Does anyone now a free (if possible open source) alternative to the Telerik DataFilter? Or maybe a tutorial how to accomplish this?

I would really want such a filter in my project.

http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/datafilter.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the telerik control uses a `CollectionViewSource` and uses the Filter event to apply the data filter.

Have a look at the [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx)

Also have a look at Bea Stollnitz blog post about it here [WPF's CollectionViewSource](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/387#.UXUgtbXvvzE)

I preffered her old site but hey ho.

This may also be worth a look [WPF Extended Datagrid](http://wpfextendeddatagrid.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I'm aware of this, but the telerik DataFilter can be applied to a DataSource, this is what I would need, because to show it with a collectionviewsource you would need all data to be loaded

Comment: @Staeff You bind the `CollectionViewSource.View` to the `DataGrid.DataSource`, should work effectively the same

Comment: With DataSource I meant a Database Datasource, and the filter would still be applied to the CollectionViewSource and not to the database query

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. Telerik usually changes products to closed source once the product reaches a high level of maturity. But you can get a license for under $2,000.